# idangerous swiper, numbers in pagination

Tags: javascript, plugins, swiper.js

It is possible to display the number of the slide in each "swiper-pagination-switch" span ? (like : 1,2,3, ...) ?

By default, the plugin creat a part of HTML like this :

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="swiper-pagination-switch swiper-visible-switch swiper-active-switch"></span>
    <span class="swiper-pagination-switch"></span>
    <span class="swiper-pagination-switch"></span></div>
</div>
```

I would like ton insert into each span the number of slide which it relates, like this :

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="swiper-pagination-switch swiper-visible-switch swiper-active-switch">1</span>
    <span class="swiper-pagination-switch">2</span>
    <span class="swiper-pagination-switch">3</span></div>
</div>
```

How I can do this ?

thanks.

Answer (score 7):

in Swiper v3.3.1 there is Demo which could fit your Question called 29-custom-pagination.html which is included in the downloaded zip:

with the option:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    paginationBulletRender: function (index, className) {
        return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
    }
```

Comment: This should be marking as the answer. Perfect solution & flexible. Goodwork.

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution, a little bit dirty, but it do the job:

```
var Swiper_slider = slider.swiper({
            pagination:          '.slider_pagination',
            paginationClickable: true,
            mode:                'horizontal',
            loop:                true,
            speed:               600,
            autoplay:            5000,
            paginationElement:   'a',
            onSwiperCreated: function(){

                $('.slider_pagination a').each(function( key ){
                    $(this).html( key + 1 );
                });

            }
});
```

Once the slider is created, a `.each()` loop add the numbers on the pagination elements.

Yannick

Answer (score 1):

Swiper v3.1.0 will have following parameter, which supports this feature.

```
paginationBulletRender(index, className)
```